# unable to delete document from partitioned collection documentdb

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using a partitioned collection in azure cosmos db.
I inserted documents into the collection. I'm trying to delete a document using the following code, but it is not getting deleted. Throws the following exception.

```
internal static bool DeleteDocumentUnderPartition(AzureDocumentDbCollectionKind collectionKind, string partitionKey, string id)
    {
        var doc = DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery(GetCollectionLink(collectionKind), new FeedOptions
        {
            PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey)
        }).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
        DocumentClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(doc.SelfLink);            
        return true;
    }
```

Value for partitionKey passed: "4c1429ca58f84e86a3f2e3d9ba1b74de"
Value for id passed: "aa20ea966258492792864c3817313b2a"

Exception -->

> DocumentClientException: Message: {"Errors":["Resource Not Found"]}
>   ActivityId: 96696cde-3ea3-41fb-bc9c-70dfd8cfac36, Request URI:
>   /apps/9dee6cc4-be09-426e-b153-f213b908337a/services/e61dcc20-86c2-4751-b4b7-53fd686d04ae/partitions/42db755a-bded-4fe9-bd4c-3561fae0aaa9/replicas/131599878429038582s,
>   RequestStats:
>
> ResponseTime: 2018-01-18T10:20:07.5146574Z, StoreReadResult:
>   StorePhysicalAddress:
>   rntbd://100.114.47.168:13700/apps/9dee6cc4-be09-426e-b153-f213b908337a/services/e61dcc20-86c2-4751-b4b7-53fd686d04ae/partitions/42db755a-bded-4fe9-bd4c-3561fae0aaa9/replicas/131599878429038582s,
>   LSN: 177530, GlobalCommittedLsn: 177530, PartitionKeyRangeId: ,
>   IsValid: True, StatusCode: 0, IsGone: False, IsNotFound: True,
>   RequestCharge: 1, ItemLSN: -1, ResourceType: Collection,
>   OperationType: Read
>
> ResponseTime: 2018-01-18T10:20:07.5146574Z, StoreReadResult:
>   StorePhysicalAddress:
>   rntbd://100.114.45.40:13700/apps/9dee6cc4-be09-426e-b153-f213b908337a/services/e61dcc20-86c2-4751-b4b7-53fd686d04ae/partitions/42db755a-bded-4fe9-bd4c-3561fae0aaa9/replicas/131606373510679694s,
>   LSN: 177530, GlobalCommittedLsn: 177530, PartitionKeyRangeId: ,
>   IsValid: True, StatusCode: 0, IsGone: False, IsNotFound: True,
>   RequestCharge: 1, ItemLSN: -1, ResourceType: Collection,
>   OperationType: Read

However, deleting a document from another collection (non-partitioned collection) works for me.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And you are sure `Database.Id` and `collectionKind.ToString()` correspond to a database and collection?

Comment: @juunas, yes! I'm able to retrieve the document from the same partitioned collection.

Comment: What is the value you're passing for the `partitionKey`?

Comment: @GauravMantri It's a string value(some guid value) mapped to the Partition key configured while creating the collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue using sample code as below but failed.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static DocumentClient client;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("***"), "***");

            var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("db", "collpart", "1");
            var reqOptions = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("1") };
            client.DeleteDocumentAsync(docUri, reqOptions).Wait();

            //block
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

My documents in the partition collection(id is my partition key) just like :

[image]

I think partition key may be the key of issue. You need to provide the value of the partition key, not the name of the field which stores the partition key.

Or you could try to create a simple new partition collection test if the document can be deleted correctly.

Hope it helps you.

---

***Update Answer:***

I think you misunderstand the meaning of `partitionkey` property in the `FeedOptions`.

For example , my container is created like this:

[image]

The partition key is "name" for my collection here. You could check your collection's partition key.

And my documents as below :

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "jay"
}

{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "jay2"
}
```

My `partitionkey` is **'name'**, so here I have two paritions : **'jay'** and **'jay1'**.

So, here you should set the `partitionkey` property to 'jay' or 'jay2',not 'name'.

If you are not setting the wrong partition key, would you please share your partition key settings and the details of the document you want to delete? (Please hide sensitive information,thank you)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated the code snippet. I'm passing the value of the partition key (4c1429ca58f84e86a3f2e3d9ba1b74de) rather than the field name itself. Yet it fails.

Comment: @VigneshT Have you tried to create new partition collection as simple as the one I posted in my answer?

Comment: Yep. No error. Haven't tried with a new partitioned collection, will try that.

Comment: @VigneshT Ok,please try it so that we could determine issue originates from the code or the database.

Comment: tried with a new partitioned collection and works fine. But with the existing collection, it throws an error which I've updated above

Comment: @VigneshT Ok,i saw your error trace.Please see my update answer.

Comment: @VigneshT Hi, any updates now? Does my update answer solved your issue?

Comment: sorry for the late response.. Seems like there was some issue in the azure cosmos db tech itself.. got fixed long back.. works fine now

Comment: @VigneshT Never mind ,you could mark this answer if you adopt it.

Comment: @JayGong Very Useful and explained answer, most of people misunderstood that they have to put key name instead of the value, I also did, but you explained it well that we need to put Value in this case and that solved the problem for me as well. Thanks !

Comment: @sumitsharma You're welcome,glad to see you find solution here.Have a nice day!